# Set proc as default method argument

Tags: ruby

I've been looking at similar questions, but couldn't find a solution to this case:

I have this class:

```
class BinarySearchTree

....

  find_work_node = Proc.new do |value, node, method|
    return if node.nil?
    if value == node.value
      node = self.send(method node)
    elsif value < node.value
      node.left = find_work_node.call(value, node.left, method)
    elsif
      node.right = find_work_node.call(value, node.right, method)
    end
    node
  end

  # Delete a specific value from the tree
  def delete(value, node = @root, block = find_work_node)
    block.call(value, node, :delete_node)
  end

....

end
```

When I try to call my `delete` method, this error appears:

```
undefined local variable or method `find_work_node' for #<BinarySearchTree:0x00000001018708> (NameError)
```

How can I set as default argument the proc `find_work_node` in the `delete` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delete method is an instance method so the default value should be a variable that can be accessed from the scope of an instance method. Either use a class variable `@@var` or an instance variable `@var`

Example:

```
class A
  @@class_var = Proc.new{|v| puts v}

  def initialize 
    @instance_var = Proc.new{|v| puts v}
  end

  def m1 a=@@class_var
    a.call "foo"
  end

  def m2 a=@instance_var
    a.call "bar"
  end

end
a = A.new
a.m1
# foo
a.m2
# bar
```

Comment: Since the value of class_var will not change, I recommend using a constant instead.  In general, using a construct that is more constrained is better because it communicates more precisely the intent and use.

Comment: @KeithBennett I agree, but it really depends on the use case. It is not clear from the Question whether there is an intent for mutability or not for the default parameter. It could be argued that since a variable was used in the first place and because this is a parameter, which in itself, is variable, then it may make sense to also allow for mutation of the default value as well. But I can also see the other side of the argument as well. The original problem, however, is scope, and not a question of mutability so any answer that addresses the scope issue is valid IMO

Comment: Agreed.  I never intended to mean that your answer was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is scope. You are defining `find_work_node` as a local variable in the class body, and this way it is scoped to the class body and only accessible inside it, but not in any methods that you define.

Note that simply changing it to an instance variable `@find_work_node` won't work because it will still be an instance variable on the class level, and although you won't get this error anymore, the `@find_work_node` variable in the method parameters will be nil. You need to initialize it in the class's `initialize` method:

```
def BinarySearchTree
    def initialize
        @find_work_node = ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `find_work_node` a class constant by defining it in all caps, then it will be accessible inside the instance method. Note in the irb session that output_bar is not accessible in an instance method, but OUTPUT_FOO is:

```
2.3.0 :001 > output_bar = -> { puts "I am bar." }; def bar; output_bar.(); end; bar
NameError: undefined local variable or method `output_bar' for main:Object
    from (irb):1:in `bar'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/kbennett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.3.0 :002 > OUTPUT_FOO = -> { puts "I am foo." }; def foo; OUTPUT_FOO.(); end; foo
I am foo.
 => nil
```

Note too that although the example uses lambdas, it doesn't matter what the data type contained by the variable is.

It would also work to define a method that returns a Proc.